# Using Jenkins SonarQube MSBuild plugin with dotnet core on linux

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core, msbuild, sonarqube

i am struggling to both understand and get the Jenkins SonarQube MSBuild to analyse a dotnet core c# project and hoped someone could help out with it. I am able to run the scan using the following commands in an "Execute Shell" build step:

dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"xxx" /n:"xxx" /v:"xxx"
dotnet build xx.sln --configuration Release
dotnet sonarscanner end

my current setup is:

Jenkins Server running on Amazon linux, on which i have installed jenkins (version 2.150.2) dotnet core and the sonarqube msbuild plugin

[jenkins@jenkins_qa sonar]# dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.104
 Commit:    73f036d4ac

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     amzn
 OS Version:  2
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.2
  Commit:  a4fd7b2c84

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.104 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

sonarqube server is installed on an Amazon Windows Instance.

I would like to use the plugin to run the analysis as this will include the report on the jenkins ui.

Thanks in advance

Comment: need to do the same, any luck? Were you able to make it work?